# SQL query not displaying the product in each sub category

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a product on each category starting from the top parent category all the way down to the category. I have my db setup like this:

```
CATEGORY TABLE:
id  |  parent_id   |  root_cat   |  name
5       37              0            bulbs
45      5               0            standard auxiliary
289     45              5            standard
297     289             5            5W
```

Now this is the products table table:

```
id    |   name    |   cat
470       bulb 5w      297
```

And this is happening, when i click on the bulbs category i see the product just fine, but when i click in the sub category standard auxiliary i do not see the product. But if i go another level to standard i can see the product again and also if i click on the 5W cat i also see the product. So the problem is only on the standard auxiliary category.

This is the method i am using to retrieve the data: 
$table_2 is the products table and $table is the category table.

```
public function getProductsWhereParentIdis($cat) {
        $check = $this->checkCategoryChildren($cat);
        if($check) {
            $query = "
            SELECT * 
            FROM categories 
            INNER JOIN products 
            ON products.category = categories.id 
            WHERE categories.id = '".$this->db->escape($cat)."' 
            OR categories.parent_id = '".$this->db->escape($cat)."' 
            OR categories.root_category = '".$this->db->escape($cat)."'";   

            return $this->db->fetchAll($query);
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table_2} WHERE category = '".$this->db->escape($cat)."'";

            return $this->db->fetchAll($query);
        }


    }
```

and this method is just to check if a product has a parent:

```
public function checkCategoryChildren($id = null) {
        if(!empty($id)) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE parent_id = '".$this->db->escape($id)."' ORDER BY view_order ASC";

            return $this->db->fetchAll($query);
        }
    }
```

and this is the fetchAll method:

```
public function query($query) {
        $this->last_query = $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    public function confirm_query($result) {
        if(!$result) {
            $output  = "Database query failed<br />";
            $output .= "Last SQL query: ". $this->last_query;
            die($output);
        } else {
            $this->affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function fetchAll($query) {
        $result = $this->query($query);
        $output = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        return $output;
    }
```

Really looking forward to anyones suggestion as to why i can see the product in all the categories but one, thank you.

Comment: How many combinations are there?

Comment: i tried 3 getting id, parent_id and another root_parent which i have not typed down but it still does not get the desired effect

Comment: dont worry Dharman, i escape every query but you just do not see it because i call a method from a different class, the escape method i call on each input relieves me of any sql injections

Comment: @Strawberry i removed the inner from the statement but it has not different effect

Comment: It's not about escaping, manual escaping is the problem. Use prepared statements with placeholder values. It means far less code and far fewer problems as a bonus.

Comment: ok thank you but if you could help me with my problem that would be great

Comment: @Dharman do you have any idea how i can achieve this

Comment: @Blu3 in the category table, why doesn't the category id = 45 has the root_cat value = 0. It should be 5.

Comment: it doesnt have it because it is coming right from the root in this case and even when i put it, it does not make a difference

Comment: So what you want you want bulb product no matter which category user clicked right? @Blu3

Comment: Another question, Is product always mapped with the last children or it may mapped with root or intermediate categories? @Blu3

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution i think you are looking for
the main problem is you are only seeing category data which are only one level up or one level down

I have also mentioned some comments in the code kindly check it.
And i also don't know how your `fetchAll()` function return the data.
eg. `object` or `array`.

**Edited:** So in this code `fetchAll()` function return the data in array format because you have used `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

```
public function getProductsWhereParentIdis($cat)
{
    $check = $this->checkCategories($cat);
    if (!empty($check)) {
        $query = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM categories 
        INNER JOIN products 
        ON products.category = categories.id 
        WHERE categories.id in (".(implode(",", $check)).")";
        return $this->db->fetchAll($query);
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table_2} WHERE category = '".$this->db->escape($cat)."'";

        return $this->db->fetchAll($query);
    }
}

public function checkCategories($cat_id)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE id = '".$this->db->escape($cat_id)."' ORDER BY view_order ASC";
    $catObj = $this->db->fetchAll($query);
    $childs = $this->getChildCategoryIds($cat_id);
    $childs[] = $cat_id;
    // you can remove the parents from here if you don't want to get all
    // products which have parents categories associated in it.
    // eg. while user click on standard then if you don't want to get the products which
    // is assigned with bulbs or standard auxiliary then return only childs.
    $parents = $this->getParentCategoryIds($catObj[0]['parent_id']);
    return array_merge($childs, $parents);
}

public function getChildCategoryIds($cat_id)
{
    $cat_array = [];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE parent_id = '".$this->db->escape($cat_id)."' ORDER BY view_order ASC";
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($q);
    foreach ($result as $value) {
        $tmp_array = $this->getChildCategoryIds($value['id']);
        $cat_array[] = $value['id'];
        if (!empty($tmp_array)) {
            $cat_array = array_merge($cat_array, $tmp_array);
        }
    }
    return $cat_array;
}

public function getParentCategoryIds($cat_id)
{
    $cat_array = [];
    $q = "SELECT * FROM {$this->table} WHERE id = '".$this->db->escape($cat_id)."' ORDER BY view_order ASC";
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($q);
    if (!empty($result[0]['parent_id'])) {
        $tmp_array = $this->getParentCategoryIds($result[0]['parent_id']);
        $cat_array[] = $result[0]['parent_id'];
        if (!empty($tmp_array)) {
            $cat_array = array_merge($cat_array, $tmp_array);
        }
    }

    return $cat_array;
}
```

Comment: i have included the fetchAll method as well for you to see, i took your code and tested it but unfortunately it did not work. in the checkCategories method you wrote $q and i changed it to $query to match the $catObj varible because it was throwing an error

Comment: then all access to the result would be like `$result[0]['parent_id']` Let me edit the answer

Comment: @Blu3 Check now

Comment: no now it does not work correctly at all. keep in mind when i click on bulbs i see the product in the last child category and the products assigned to each other category under the top main category, the only problem is in the second tier, here let me add some photos for you to see the results with my code

Comment: done, just added them, tell me if you understand it completely

Comment: Ok give me 2 min i will get back to you @Blu3

Comment: I have updated the code and test it locally with the data structure you given and i am able to get bulb if the category is `standard auxiliary` @Blu3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198663/discussion-between-dhaval-purohit-and-blu3).

Comment: so based on what i can see here i no longer need the root_category at all for this to work

Comment: thank you very much, it is amazing what you did and i will definitely learn a lot from this, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT c.olumms
     , i.actually
     , w.ant
  FROM categories c
  JOIN products p
    ON p.category = c.id 
 WHERE :mystring IN (c.root_category,c.parent_id,c.id);
```

Comment: what is the :mystring IN.... i do not understand how i should type this

Comment: See about placeholders for prepared and bound queries

Comment: but this does not work because when i enter the first sub like fiat it does not show anything unless i go to hatchback or saloon, you understand?

Comment: This comes back to my first comment

Comment: it goes like this:

Auto -> Bulbs - > Standard Auxiliary - > Standard - > 1.2W

Comment: when clicking on bulbs i see everything from 1.2W but when i click on standard auxiliary it does not show anything unless i go one more level to standard, then i can see the 1.2W. Hope this is clear

Comment: did this answer your first comment?

Comment: No. I was expecting a number.

Comment: could you please help me out as i do not understand what you are seeking. for example in my case you can start from the bulbs part and if we go all the way down to 1.2W. it means it is 3. is this the number you are expecting?

Comment: strawberry please help me out

Comment: around 3k of products and less than 300 for categories

Comment: Well, you can probably hold 3k in memory quite efficiently, so I would be tempted to push everything into json and parse it with some javascript - but that doesn't help you with your organizational problem, which (although you can solve it with your present model), I'd instead be tempted to solve with a different model. Maybe take a look at nested sets.

Comment: so you have no suggestions how i can achieve this with a sql query?

Comment: i ask because every category works except one which tells me that everything is fine i just need to figure out why only one category the product is not being displayed